# How to initialize the Shared Preferences values ​using an xml file for the first time in Android Studio

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to initialize the Shared Preferences values ​​using a .xml file only for the first time in Android Studio, I need these values ​​to be read only the first time because then these values ​​will be replaced according to the user's needs.

Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
private static final String mypreference = "mypref";
private EditText mpAddress;
private EditText mPort;
private String mconfig_IpAddress;
private String mconfig_Port;
private Button mInit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, R.xml.initial_setup, false);

    mpAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etx_ipaddress);
    mPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etx_port);
    mInit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_init);

    mInit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            leerConfigWiFiShareref();
            mpAddress.setText(mconfig_IpAddress);
            mPort.setText(mconfig_Port);
        }
    });

}

private void leerConfigWiFiShareref() {
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedpreferences.contains("SP_ConfigIpAddress")) {
        mconfig_IpAddress = sharedpreferences.getString("SP_ConfigIpAddress", "");
    }
    if (sharedpreferences.contains("SP_ConfigPort")) {
        mconfig_Port = sharedpreferences.getString("SP_ConfigPort", "");
    }
  }
}
```

And my .xml file `initial_setu.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditTextPreference
    android:id="@+id/et1_ip_address"
    android:key="SP_ConfigIpAddress"
    android:defaultValue="192.168.4.1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHighlight="#00ffffff"
    android:title="IP Address" />

<EditTextPreference
    android:id="@+id/et1_port"
    android:key="SP_ConfigPort"
    android:defaultValue="8888"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHighlight="#00ffffff"
    android:title="Port" />

  </PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already put `readAgain` to `false` it means it only read the first time.

> readAgain boolean: Whether to re-read the default values. If false, this method will set the default values only if this method has never been called in the past (or if the KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES in the default value shared preferences file is false). To attempt to set the default values again bypassing this check, set readAgain to true.

When you call this, it means you using default `SharedPreference` of your app.

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.initial_setup, false);
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) // you have to use this
```

If you using the custom name you should try this

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, R.xml.initial_setup, false);
```

Comment: Công Hải, I have done it as you suggest but when reading the SP I only get null value